# sqlhelper output parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

**i am working on SQLHelper class. and  how  to get  @Email value**
 ????????

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
         bl.user_id = TextBox1.Text;
         DataTable  dt= bl.forget();
         if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
         {
             Response.Write(  dt.Rows[0]["@Email"].ToString());
         }
        }
        catch (Exception g)
        {
            Response.Write(g.Message);
        }
    }
```

Bll part.......

```
 DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(bl.str, CommandType.StoredProcedure,     
               "forFetPasswo",new SqlParameter("@Email", bl.user_id));
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
                    {
                      dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                    return dt;
```

sql part.......

```
Alter PROCEDURE  Abc
    @Email nvarchar(100)output
AS
BEGIN
     if (@Email !=null)
      begin
       if exists(select * from UserLogin where Emailid =@Email )
         begin
          select @Email ='mail send'
         end           
       end
        else
        begin
         select @Email='invalid email id'
        end

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an output parameter but not handling it in the .net code. You are looking for a dataset.

The quick fix is to add `select @Email AS email` to your stored proc at the end

Otherwise, change `new SqlParameter` to another [overload that uses direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t547y10h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure you only assign the @Email variable, you should add something like that to the end of stored procedure

```
 select @Email as Email
```

And access it in code

```
Response.Write(  dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString());
```

And remove `output` parameter ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Your Case use Either User DataSet or Output parameter...
Since You Are Returning Only One Value....use Output Parameter.

```
var param=new SqlParameter("@Email",SqlDBType.VarChar,100).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(con,Abc,param);
var Email=param.Value.toString();
```

Also in SP use SET instead of SELECT if u can....btw it doesn't matter much